# Giving the same id to two different components in an xml file Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am using a constraint layout in my XML file. I have a view like in the example. Imageview and textview. I want both of these to have the same action after clicking. How can I group the two together and give them an id?

xml :

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_drawerLogout"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_exit"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_drawerLogout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:text="@string/sign_out_text"/>
```

Comment: You can use a single `TextView` with a `startDrawable`.

Comment: I think my question was not understood. I want to use same id for imageview and textview. @Alpha1

Comment: Got it. You can't have two views with the same Id in a same hierarchy.

Comment: Don't forget you can use the `onClick` xml attribute for both set to the same method : `android:onClick="myOneMethod"` and implement the `myOneMethod(View)` in your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My layout was inside a constraintlayout and in this case I used the constraintlayout group component.

xml :

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_logout"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_exit"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_drawerLogout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:text="@string/sign_out_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_choice"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_logout"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_star" />


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                    android:id="@+id/logout_group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="img_logout,menu_drawerLogout" />
```

Then I created the Group.setAllOnClickListener field in MainActivity :

```
 private fun Group.setAllOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener?) {
        referencedIds.forEach { id ->
            rootView.findViewById<View>(id).setOnClickListener(listener)
        }
    }
```

and

```
 logoutGroup.setAllOnClickListener()
         logOutDialog()
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 components with the same id in an XML layout resource file.

### Method 1

If you want both to have the same action set a common `onClickListener` to both like,

**xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_exit"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_out_text"/>
```

**inside onCreate method**

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // action
    }
});

imageView.setOnClickListener(myListener);
textView.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

### Method 2

You can put both the views in a container and then set a `onClickListener` to the container

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_exit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_out_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**inside onCreate**

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.container);

View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // action
    }
});

layout.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code below:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/location"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/openLoc" />
```

You can but it is not recommended.
Set ids in a way that elements can be easily identifiable by ID like android:id="@+id/txtLocation" android:id="@+id/imgLocation" it makes it easy to identify element type just by reading ID. You can make it even easier by appending layout name in beginning like android:id="@+id/profileTxtLocation". Now this will help you while coding as autocomplete feature will assist you. Just type layout name you will get the list of all layout elements, then you will type the kind of element you get the list of all asked elements(es: textViews) in layout.